# Static files doesn't work on heroku when using primary key in url

Tags: python, django, heroku, settings, primary-key

I have a problem, static files does not work when there is primary key in the url, problem occurs locally and on heroku. I tried many settings configs and always there was one problem or another.

you can check it, how it looks over this link - https://ibb.co/znv8Fqj

```
from pathlib import Path

import django_heroku
import dj_database_url
import os


# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY ='smth'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['optifolio-dev.herokuapp.com','127.0.0.1','[*]']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'optifolio',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',

    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'OPI.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'OPI.wsgi.application'



AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles/')

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images/')
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

I bet that there is a problem with heroku config but I can't find it any help will be great!

my main html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Optifolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="..\static\css\main.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mulish&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
    
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- semantic UI -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.14/semantic.min.css">
    <!--Chart js-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js" integrity="sha256-Uv9BNBucvCPipKQ2NS9wYpJmi8DTOEfTA/nH2aoJALw=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.css" integrity="sha256-aa0xaJgmK/X74WM224KMQeNQC2xYKwlAt08oZqjeF0E=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>



</head>
<body>
    {% include 'optifolio/navbar.html' %}
    {% block content %}
    
    
    {% endblock %}

</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

And html site where problem occur:

````
{% extends 'optifolio/main.html' %} 

{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<br>
<div class="container" style="margin-left:230px;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <p class="text-md-left" style="font-size:36px;font-weight:bold;">Wizualizacja portfolio</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container" style="margin-left:230px;">
    
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div id="navbarResponsive">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><button class="przyciskportf1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"><div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">Dodaj transakcję</div></button></a>
                        </li>              
                    </ul>

                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    
</div>

<div class="container" style="margin-left:250px;">
    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="{% url 'add_transaction' %}">Dodaj</a>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Dodaj transakcję</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">

              <form action="/visualisationpage/#" method="POST">
                  {% csrf_token %}
                  {{ form.non_field_errors }}
                  <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="{{ form.title.id_for_label }}">Nazwa spółki</label>
                        <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Podaj nazwę spółki">
                        {{ form.title.errors }}
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="{{ form.buy_sell.id_for_label }}"></label>
                        <label for="buy">Kupno</label><br>
                        <input type="radio" id="buy" name="buy_sell" class="form-control" value="+">
                        <label for="sell">Sprzedaz</label><br>
                        <input type="radio" id="sell" name="buy_sell" class="form-control" value="-">
                        {{ form.buy_sell.errors }}
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="{{ form.shares_number.id_for_label }}">Liczba akcji</label>
                        <input type="text" name="shares_number" class="form-control">
                        {{ form.shares_number.errors }}
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="{{ form.course.id_for_label }}">Kurs</label>
                        <input type="text" name="course" class="form-control">
                        {{ form.course.errors }}
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="{{ form.fare.id_for_label }}">Opłata transakcyjna</label>
                        <input type="text" name="fare" class="form-control">
                        {{ form.fare.errors }}
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="{{ form.date.id_for_label }}">Data</label>
                        <input type="date" name="date" class="form-control">
                        {{ form.date.errors }}
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="{{ form.hour.id_for_label }}">Godzina</label>
                        <input type="time" name="hour" class="form-control">
                        {{ form.hour.errors }}
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" value="Zapisz zmiany" href="{% url 'visualisationpage' %}" class="btn btn-primary">Zapisz zmiany</button>
              </form>
          </div>


      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="overlay"></div>
<div class="container" style="margin-left:250px;">
  <table  class="table table-bordered" style="max-width:700px;">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th class="text-center">Nazwa</th>
              <th class="text-center">Data</th>
              <th class=" text-center">Godzina</th>
              <th class=" text-center">Liczba akcji</th>
              <th class=" text-center">Kwota</th>
              <th class=" text-center">Opłata</th>
              <th class=" text-center">Edytuj</th>
              <th class=" text-center">Usuń</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {% for temp in visdata %}
          <tr>
              <th class=" text-center">{{ temp.title }}</th>
              <td class=" text-center">{{ temp.date }}</td>
              <td class=" text-center">{{ temp.hour }}</td>
              <td class=" text-center">{{ temp.shares_number }}</td>
              <td class=" text-center">{{ temp.course }}</td>
              <td class=" text-center">{{ temp.fare }}</td>
              <td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="{% url 'update_transaction' temp.visdata_id %}">Edytuj</a></td>
              <td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="{% url 'delete_transaction' temp.visdata_id %}">Usuń</a></td>
          </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>

    <div class="container" style="margin-left:250px;">
      <left>
      <button class="wykres szarak" onclick="chartType('bar')">Bar</button>
      <button class="wykres szarak" onclick="chartType('line')">Line</button>
      <button class="wykres szarak" onclick="chartType('doughnut')">Doughnut</button>
      <button class="wykres szarak" onclick="chartType('pie')">Pie</button>
      <button class="wykres szarak" onclick="chartType('polarArea')">PolarArea</button>
    
    </div>

    <div class="chartCard"style="margin-left:250px;">
      <div class="chartBox" style="max-width:800px">
        <canvas id="myChart" width="50" height="20"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>

    const data = {

          labels: [{% for item in visdata %}'{{item.title}}',{%endfor%}],
          datasets: [{
            label: 'Shares number',
            data: [{% for item in visdata %}'{{item.shares_number}}',{%endfor%}],
            backgroundColor: [
              'rgba(255, 26, 104, 0.2)',
              'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
              'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
              'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
              'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
              'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
              'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
              'rgba(255, 26, 104, 1)',
              'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
              'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
              'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
              'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
              'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
              'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
          }]
        };
        
    // config 
    const config = {
      type: 'line',
      data,
      options: {
        scales: {
          y: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }
      }
    };
        // config 
        const config2 = {
      type: 'bar',
      data,
      options: {
        scales: {
          y: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }
      }
    };
        // config 
        const config3 = {
      type: 'pie',
      data,
      options: {}
    };
        const config4 = {
      type: 'doughnut',
      data: data,
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        plugins: {
          legend: {
            position: 'top',
          },
        }
      },
    };
        const config5 = {
      type: 'polarArea',
      data: data,
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        plugins: {
          legend: {
            position: 'top',
          },
          title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Chart.js Polar Area Chart'
          }
        }
      },
    };

    // render init block
    let myChart = new Chart(
      document.getElementById('myChart'),
      config
    );

    function chartType(type){
      myChart.destroy();
      if (type =='line'){
        myChart = new Chart(
        document.getElementById('myChart'),
        config
        );
      }
      if (type =='bar'){
        myChart = new Chart(
        document.getElementById('myChart'),
        config2
        );
      }
      if (type =='pie'){
        myChart = new Chart(
        document.getElementById('myChart'),
        config3
        );
      }
      if (type =='doughnut'){
        myChart = new Chart(
        document.getElementById('myChart'),
        config4
        );
      }
      if (type =='polarArea'){
        myChart = new Chart(
        document.getElementById('myChart'),
        config5
        );
      }
    }
    </script>
    </div>

  {% endblock %}
```[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPe1A.png
````

Comment: It's woking fine and you've provided protected url so we can't check what is your problem. provide some code of your template where this happning

Comment: Edited and added a picture, thanks for tip : )

Comment: Hello @Maksym Kokocinski still it's hard to say can you provide code of HTML document where this happning

Comment: I added 2 html codes, one with main and the second one where the problem occur

Comment: You've added two bootstrap css cdn that's why it's happening remove one and it should resolve

Comment: I don't think thats the problem, because other sites work well, only if I use primary key the statics doesn't load. Deleted one bootstrap and css and nothing changed : / Do you have other ideas?

Comment: Did you provided correct page (page which is used on pk in url). Is there any error inside your browser console?

Comment: Fixed, link in main was wrong:
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">

Comment: Glad to hear that you solved your problem 